# set parameter once layout is closed

Tags: android, layout

I created a layout in android that is called MyChatActivity.

When I exit this activity and move to another activity, I had like to save the exit time so I could use it later for last seen and so on.

Inside this layout, there are many buttons (home,profile,search) that lead to a different layout.

Basically, I can add to each one of these buttons the same code of saving the time variable.

I was wondering if there is a method that is set when the layout is closed, so I could write this code only in one place when the layout is closed (doesn't matter from which buttons it was closed)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1>You can override the onPause()  while going to the next activity.

```
 @Override
  public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
       // Save your time
    }
```